# How to migrate a SQL Server database on my computer to AWS RDS?

Tags: sql-server, amazon-web-services, migration, database-migration, sql-server-express

I have a SQL Server Express database on my machine that I want to migrate to an AWS RDS instance. I don't know how to do that or where to start from. Any idea would be really appreciated! Thank you

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it is lacking a specific question and is only asking for ideas, which is off topic for Stack Overflow.

Comment: @Larnu I was thinking it was for mutual help and finding answers to your question !!

Comment: The [Importing and Exporting SQL Server Databases user guide](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html) is a good place to start. Found it with an internet search on "How to migrate sql server db on my computer to aws rds?".

Comment: I search all over the internet and watch many videos and articles on the topic. Still looking for some answers !! How do i migrate my DB to AWS ?

Answer (score 1):

There are a few directions you could take to migrate your database across.

One approach is the simple backup export and import approach:

- Export a backup of your SQL Server Express DB
- Create an S3 bucket in the same region as your RDS instance.
- Use the native SQL Server `msdb.dbo.rds_restore_database` procedure on your RDS.

There is a lot of information available regarding this solution that AWS has detailed in [this article](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.html#SQLServer.Procedural.Importing.Native.Using.Restore). This solution should be the easiest for you with the least overhead.

Other solutions that people have used are:

- [Database Migration Service](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/dms/latest/userguide/CHAP_Source.SQLServer.html).
- [Data Pipeline](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/datapipeline/latest/DeveloperGuide/what-is-datapipeline.html).

These are great solutions, but if you're just trying to perform a one time export of a DB on your PC the first solution has the least moving parts and configuration.

Comment: Ok, I'll try the first solution and see how it goes !!

Comment: Hope it goes well for you

Comment: I tried the first solution i created the bakup but the backup file does not exist in the destination folder !!!

Comment: You uploaded it to your S3 bucket but it does not exist?

Comment: No, I when to the destination folder to upload it but there was nothing with the same inside the folder !!

Comment: hence i use a recent version of the SQL server management studio !!

Comment: Which destination folder? Are you referring to exporting your database to your local or uploading it to S3?

Comment: The backup file was not generated or something like that.

Comment: i even tried to upload it with s3 bucket but there was nothing in the folder.

Comment: Can you follow these on your pc? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/backup-restore/create-a-full-database-backup-sql-server?view=sql-server-ver15. Then upload that to S3